# R Data frame column update

Tags: r, dictionary, dataframe, left-join, no-match

I have a dataframe with names
I have a second dataframe with a dictionary of names and the sex of those names
I want to check if the name is in the dictionary if it is then add the sex from the dictionary table to the names dataframe

My code looks like below

```
# Sets everything to -1, 1 for male, 0 for female
train$sex <- "-1"
train$sex[toupper(train$fname) == nam_dict$Name]<-nam_dict$Sex
```

I am getting the following error

```
Error in train$sex[toupper(train$fname) == nam_dict$Name] <- nam_dict$Sex : 
NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
In addition: Warning message:
In toupper(train$fname) == nam_dict$Name :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I have a work around - i think - where i can split the dictionary into male and female and simply replace the ***<-nam_dict$Sex*** portion of the code with the character 'F' or 'M' depending on the dictionary

I just thought there would be a better way

Comment: First of all its not clear if `train` and `nam_dict` of the same size, but even if they were, you are subsetting `train$sex` by condition and inserting `nam_dict$Sex` into without subsetting it too. Also, the message `NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments` usually means that your subset operation returned `NA`s and R not sure where it should insert the data to. Either way, this is not reproducible as we don't have both data sets so I doubt anyone can help you really.

Comment: Hi David, train and nam_dict are different sizes. The dictionary can be gotten from the link [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/20260-gender-verification-by-forename-cmd-line-tool-db/). I took the file nam_dict.txt from it. The train dataset can be gotten from [here](https://www.ssb.no/en/befolkning/statistikker/navn/aar/2015-01-27?fane=tabell&sort=nummer&tabell=215662). Its from the central statistics office in Norway

Comment: I'm certainly not going to download these data sets (someone maybe will though). I only can help if you will provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). I also think that within the process of making this example you will understand what's wrong with your code. Wish you luck either way.

Comment: Thanks @David, that seems fair enough. You mentioned in your first post that i wasnt subsetting my nam_dict$Sex, Could you tell me how to do this. In essence if the first names match eg row 1 column 1 of the nam_dict is equal to the train data, i want to add row 1 column 2 of the nam_dict to the train data. Again thank you for your time. I will have a look at the NAs. It might be because of recycling or the dictionary might not have been cleaned correctly

Comment: Something like `train$sex[toupper(train$fname) == nam_dict$Name] <- nam_dict$Sex[toupper(train$fname) == nam_dict$Name]` probably, but it seems like you additional error there (which I also mentioned). Though this code doesn't make much sense to me if `train` and `nam_dict` are of different sizes. Try just doing `toupper(train$fname) == nam_dict$Name` and see what happens. I think you are doing it all wrong.

Comment: Yep, i have found the reason for the NA message, it appears an extra row was inserted because i imported it from excel and column one contained a comma i hadn't noticed. One down. How would do the comparison if my way seems clumsy - something like rbind? Again, genuinely thanks for your help

Comment: Take a look at `match` or maybe `merge`

Comment: Ok, nvm, I'll write something for you in a minute just because you are very polite and because I want to teach you how to provide a reproducible example in R

Comment: In case you don't know, this is called a ***join*** or ***merge*** operation, like in SQL. Specifically, **LEFT JOIN**. In this case your slight twist is you need to perform a case-insensitive match on the name column, and some names may still no-match anyway (not found in the namelist), in which case the output should keep that name with NA in the sex column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem can be solved by a quick and simple implementation of `match`.
First, here's a quick reproducible example

```
(train <- data.frame(fname = c("Alex", "Jennifer", "David", "Alice")))
#      fname
# 1     Alex
# 2 Jennifer
# 3    David
# 4    Alice
(nam_dict <- data.frame(Name = c("alice", "alex"), Sex = 0:1))
#    Name Sex
# 1 alice   0
# 2  alex   1
```

A possible solution

```
train$sex <- nam_dict$Sex[match(tolower(train$fname), tolower(nam_dict$Name))]
train
#      fname sex
# 1     Alex   1
# 2 Jennifer  NA
# 3    David  NA
# 4    Alice   0
```

---

Al bit more advanced solution (if you''ll ever work with huge data sets) is to try `data.table`s *binary join* which allows you to update your data *by reference*, chose which columns to update while everything is done in a lightning speed.

First we will convert both data sets to `data.table` class and make both columns lower case, then we will `key` them by the column we want join by, finally we do a left join to `train` while creating the `sex` column by reference and pulling the data from `i` (Sex column in `nam_dict`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(train)[, fname := tolower(fname)]
setDT(nam_dict)[, Name := tolower(Name)]
setkey(train, fname) ; setkey(nam_dict, Name)
train[nam_dict, sex := i.Sex]
train
#       fname sex
# 1:     alex   1
# 2:    alice   0
# 3:    david  NA
# 4: jennifer  NA
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you - Timezones - this is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you for the answer and especially the huge data sets (next step). I have also noted the re-produceable method example and will use this method from now on when asking questions